# How to change the image of an ImageButton when the user click the button

Tags: java, android, onclick, imagebutton

I was 3 hours trying to make an ImageButton that changes its Image when the user click, but It is impossible to me. Thanks in advance!

Main Clas

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageButton dado_btn = (ImageButton) findViewById (R.id.dado_button);

    replace = R.drawable.face_1;
    dado_btn.setBackgroundResource(replace);
}

    public void OnClickTirada (View v){
       //this doesn't work at all 
       dado_btn.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.face_1));          
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dado_btn` is only defined locally in `onCreate()` and thus you can't use it in any other method.

To make this work you have to declare a field `dado_btn`, which you might have done already if your code compiles. As a second step don't declare the local variable in `onCreate()`.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    dado_btn = (ImageButton) findViewById (R.id.dado_button);
    ...
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, thank you so much!
I should ask before! haha